# Uploading an apostrophe-file renames it and prompts a download

Tags: apostrophe-cms

When adding an `apostrophe-file` via the CMS, there are two weird things that occur:

1. The browser prompts a download of the file I just uploaded (!?)
2. The actual uploaded file is renamed to include the id

The first event is weird, but could be overlooked, as we would immediately delete that duplicated file. Why does that occur though?

The second part is quite problematic however. We are uploading a PDF to make available for users to download, and the files end up with a ridiculous name like `cko3d177z000h8e3jpnpqi15f-advertising-offer.pdf`, which is not a good look to the users downloading that file. Is there a way to prevent this renaming?

Our alternate solution is to add those files to the version control (e.g. the `public` directory) and then have the editor use a URL instead of navigating in the CMS, but this is cumbersome, and requires dev knowledge and access, which we are trying to prevent.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. This seems like more of a discussion topic or "bug" report. Files get new filenames because if someone uploads another `advertising-offer.pdf` then you run into conflicts and have to rename that file anyway. For public-facing file URLs I'd generally go with a redirect that I can edit later rather than the actual file URL. All that said, it could be worth raising the issue of adding a method to govern file naming to slide in here: https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/main/lib/modules/apostrophe-attachments/lib/api.js#L104

Comment: I guess the first question would be: why am I prompted to download the file I just uploaded? That feels like a useless step to ask users. 
 
Then, I understand the logic of having different names if we cared about versions, which we don't in this case. Either way, the issue is when the file is presented to the fornt end user, then it should be named with the slug only, not whatever ID/version it has on the server.

Comment: The download thing might be a bug. It's a piece with a `_url` property. Most pieces redirect to their pages if they have a URL, so in this case it's redirecting to the file. Worth a bug report. The slug is different from the file URL. Slugs influence URLs when a template is rendered, which isn't the case with a file. Apostrophe isn't involved in the request for a file URL.

Comment: The download was a bug, and is fixed in beta 1, which was released yesterday.

Comment: As for the filenames, it's about guaranteeing uniqueness as alexbea said, but we hear you when you say this probably isn't the ideal way to do it.